# Silverlight Center during Zoom animation

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to create zoom in/out buttons on a canvas. The zooming works, however the canvas zooms in/out towards or away from the top left corner of the container. I would like to zoom to the center.

I followed along with the following question/answer to get a zoom feature to work in my Silverlight application.

[Silverlight 3 - ScaleTransform or other method to zoom in a Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030367/silverlight-3-scaletransform-or-other-method-to-zoom-in-a-canvas)

The accepted answer makes use of

```
CenterAnimationX
```

and

```
CenterAnimationY
```

I'm not sure how these are/could be defined, and since the question is over 2 years old I don't think I'll get a response there. I'm guessing these animations would be defined as part of the storyboard in the original question. Can anyone give me a hint on how the xaml would look for this centering animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using scale transform in the `RenderTransform` property of the `Canvas` then to center the zoom specify the `RenderTransformOrigin` property on the `Canvas` to be  "0.5, 0.5".

Comment: Wow, never would have found that. Thanks.